# Direcionar a porta 5060 (SIP Asterisk) para eth1

Tags: iptables

Eu estou pretendendo usar o iptables no CentOS 6.5 para todas as saídas do Freepbx (Asterisk) via eth1.

Eu tenho duas interfaces de rede:

eth0 --> rede interna (para a conexão de PCs com o softphone)
eth1 --> internet (Todas as saídas do Voip)

A regra: `iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 5060 -j MARK --set-mark 1`

Quero direcionar o SIP para somente o eth1, mas eu não tenho sucesso

Comment: Caramba, quem clicou no negativo e nem explicou o porque? Como posso saber fazer direito?

Comment: Não esquenta, isso acontece. Veja aqui, já usei essa página como referência: http://asteriskbrasil.org/pipermail/asteriskbrasil/2006-December/012267.html

Answer (score 1):

Voce precisa direcionar além das portas 5060 de registro, também as portas RTP, senão você só se autenticará mas não passará audio.

Answer (score 1):

A asterisk utiliza a porta 5060 **UDP** por padrão, portanto, a não ser que você tenha alterado o transporte da sinalização SIP para TCP, pode ser este o problema.

Além disso o asterisk utiliza um intervalo de portas altas para o tráfego do áudio/vídeo: 10000 à 20000 UDP, e é necessário criar regras para este intervalo também.